# Measure of random Voronoi cell

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be some distribution (with density) on $\mathbb{R}^d$, from which we independently draw $X_1,\ldots,X_n$. These induce a Voronoi partition on $\mathbb{R}^d$: $V_1$ is the set of all points closest to $X_1$, and so forth till $V_n$ (since $\mu$ has a density, ties will almost surely not occur). I am interested in the random variable $Y_i=\mu(V_i)$. From symmetry, we have $E[Y_i]=1/n$. On the line, one can show that $Y_i$ is distributed exponentially with parameter $n$ (this is known for $\mu$ uniform over $[0,1]$ but I think a simple argument extends this to arbitrary $\mu$). What is known about the distribution of $Y_i$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ for general $\mu$?

Comment: Your question is inexactly formulated: there are unbounded Voronoi cells.

Comment: @user64494 Yes, but the question asks about its $\mu$-measure which is finite.

Comment: @Dmitry Karachun: Why do you think so? Also the statement " From symmetry, we have $E[Y_i]=1/n$" is ungrounded.

Comment: I doubt much is known at that level of generality. A related model that is often studied in the physics literature is the case of the Poisson process on R^d. Your model should approach that model as n goes to infinity if you rescale Y by n. See E.g. https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.70.066119

Comment: @user64494 Well, it's written in the question: $Y_i=\mu(V_i)$, where $\mu$ is the probability measure we use for sampling $X_i$. The expectation of all $Y_i$ is the same and $\sum Y_i$ is always equal to $1$, so expectation is indeed $1/n$.

Comment: @Dmitry Karachun: Why "The expectation of all $Y_i$ is the same"?

Comment: @user64494 Well, formally, exchanging points $X_i$ and $X_j$ is measure preserving and maps $Y_i$ to $Y_j$, so all $Y_i$ have the same law. Informally, though, there is just complete symmetry between points.

Comment: @Dmitry Karachun  Your arguments are similar to the following: $x=y$ if the ones are solutions of the system $x \cdot y=a, x+y=b$.

Comment: @user64494 This conversation starts to be seeming futile but let me try one more time. In your example there are two ordered solutions $(x,y)$ to the system of equations. If $(x,y)$ is a uniformly random solution (among two possible solutions) then distributions of $x$ and $y$ are the same because the map which exchanges $x$ and $y$ is measure preseving (nott that this does not mean that $x=y$ a.s.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See

*Rathie, P. N.*, [**On the volume distribution of the typical Poisson-Delaunay cell**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/3214909), J. Appl. Probab. 29, No. 3, 740-744 (1992). [ZBL0768.52014](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0768.52014).

(summary - it's complicated but tractable).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you find this useful:
[On the measure of Voronoi cells, Devroye et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.04267)